# importing SVG symbols to postgres

Tags: qgis

im working with with QGIS 2.14.2 server version with postgres 9.5 database.
i want to know how to import SVG symbols stored in QGIS library  into POSTGRES?

Answer (score 2):

SVG defines the graphics in XML format,so first you need to export those svg symbols as xml files and save them to some path on your disk then you can refer to [import xml to postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007884/import-xml-files-to-postgresql/19013822#19013822) to import xml files in your postgres database.